# Exception when running latest version of Activiti

Tags: activiti

I'm getting the following exception:

> Exception: Caused by:
>   org.activiti.engine.impl.javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Cannot
>   resolve identifier 'notEnoughInformation'

while running on `Activiti` version 5.19.0.

I am getting an above exception and it hangs. Anyone has an idea why is this happening?

Full log here :

```
ltAsyncJobExecutor].
04:24:43,502 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.DefaultAsyncJobExecutor  - Creating thread pool queue of size 100
04:24:43,502 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.DefaultAsyncJobExecutor  - Creating executor service with corePoolSize 2, maxPoolSize 10 and keepAliveTime 5000
04:24:43,506 [Thread-5] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.AcquireTimerJobsRunnable  - {} starting to acquire async jobs due
04:24:43,514 [Thread-6] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.AcquireAsyncJobsDueRunnable  - {} starting to acquire async jobs due
04:24:43,626 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.activiti.explorer.conf.DemoDataConfiguration  - Initializing demo groups
04:24:43,815 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.activiti.explorer.conf.DemoDataConfiguration  - Initializing demo users
04:24:44,004 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.activiti.explorer.conf.DemoDataConfiguration  - Initializing demo process definitions
04:24:44,047 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.activiti.explorer.conf.DemoDataConfiguration  - Initializing demo models
04:24:44,063 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.activiti.explorer.conf.DemoDataConfiguration  - Initializing demo report data
04:24:44,079 [Thread-7] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.DefaultAsyncJobExecutor  - Shutting down the default async job executor [org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.DefaultAsyncJobExecutor].
04:24:44,082 [Thread-5] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.AcquireTimerJobsRunnable  - {} stopped async job due acquisition
04:24:44,082 [Thread-6] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.AcquireAsyncJobsDueRunnable  - {} stopped async job due acquisition
04:24:44,126 [Thread-7] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource org/activiti/explorer/demo/process/Helpdesk.png
04:24:44,126 [Thread-7] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource org/activiti/explorer/demo/process/Helpdesk.bpmn20.xml
04:24:44,593 [Thread-7] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource org/activiti/explorer/demo/process/reviewSalesLead.reviewSaledLead.png
04:24:44,600 [Thread-7] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource org/activiti/explorer/demo/process/VacationRequest.png
04:24:44,600 [Thread-7] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource org/activiti/explorer/demo/process/FixSystemFailureProcess.png
04:24:44,600 [Thread-7] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource org/activiti/explorer/demo/process/createTimersProcess.bpmn20.xml
04:24:44,623 [Thread-7] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource org/activiti/explorer/demo/process/FixSystemFailureProcess.bpmn20.xml
04:24:44,635 [Thread-7] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource org/activiti/explorer/demo/process/simple-approval.bpmn20.xml
04:24:44,659 [Thread-7] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource org/activiti/explorer/demo/process/simple-approval.simpleApprovalProcess.png
04:24:44,659 [Thread-7] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource org/activiti/explorer/demo/process/VacationRequest.bpmn20.xml
04:24:44,666 [Thread-7] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource org/activiti/explorer/demo/process/reviewSalesLead.bpmn20.xml
Exception in thread "Thread-7" org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Unknown property used in expression: ${notEnoughInformation == 'true'}
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.el.JuelExpression.getValue(JuelExpression.java:53)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.el.UelExpressionCondition.evaluate(UelExpressionCondition.java:53)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.ExclusiveGatewayActivityBehavior.leave(ExclusiveGatewayActivityBehavior.java:69)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.FlowNodeActivityBehavior.execute(FlowNodeActivityBehavior.java:36)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationActivityExecute.execute(AtomicOperationActivityExecute.java:60)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:633)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:628)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.eventNotificationsCompleted(AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.java:52)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:56)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:633)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:628)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:49)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:633)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:628)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionCreateScope.execute(AtomicOperationTransitionCreateScope.java:49)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:633)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:628)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerTake.execute(AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerTake.java:80)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:633)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:628)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionDestroyScope.execute(AtomicOperationTransitionDestroyScope.java:116)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:633)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:628)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerEnd.eventNotificationsCompleted(AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerEnd.java:35)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:56)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:633)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:628)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:49)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:633)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:628)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.take(ExecutionEntity.java:452)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.take(ExecutionEntity.java:430)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.BpmnActivityBehavior.performOutgoingBehavior(BpmnActivityBehavior.java:140)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.BpmnActivityBehavior.performDefaultOutgoingBehavior(BpmnActivityBehavior.java:66)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.FlowNodeActivityBehavior.leave(FlowNodeActivityBehavior.java:44)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.AbstractBpmnActivityBehavior.leave(AbstractBpmnActivityBehavior.java:47)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.UserTaskActivityBehavior.signal(UserTaskActivityBehavior.java:225)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.signal(ExecutionEntity.java:409)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.TaskEntity.complete(TaskEntity.java:203)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.CompleteTaskCmd.execute(CompleteTaskCmd.java:52)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.CompleteTaskCmd.execute(CompleteTaskCmd.java:24)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.NeedsActiveTaskCmd.execute(NeedsActiveTaskCmd.java:59)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvoker.execute(CommandInvoker.java:24)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:57)
        at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:47)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
        at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:45)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:31)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:40)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:35)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.TaskServiceImpl.complete(TaskServiceImpl.java:175)
        at org.activiti.explorer.conf.DemoDataConfiguration$1.run(DemoDataConfiguration.java:278)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.activiti.engine.impl.javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Cannot resolve identifier 'notEnoughInformation'
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.juel.AstIdentifier.eval(AstIdentifier.java:83)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.juel.AstBinary$SimpleOperator.eval(AstBinary.java:27)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.juel.AstBinary.eval(AstBinary.java:106)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.juel.AstEval.eval(AstEval.java:50)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.juel.AstNode.getValue(AstNode.java:26)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.juel.TreeValueExpression.getValue(TreeValueExpression.java:114)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.delegate.ExpressionGetInvocation.invoke(ExpressionGetInvocation.java:33)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.delegate.DelegateInvocation.proceed(DelegateInvocation.java:37)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.delegate.DefaultDelegateInterceptor.handleInvocation(DefaultDelegateInterceptor.java:25)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.el.JuelExpression.getValue(JuelExpression.java:48)
        ... 60 more
```

Comment: I faced problems in running activiti latest version because it will try to use servlet 3.X so make sure you  have  servlet 3.X onwards.

Comment: Below are the servlet details in the tomcat/lib directory. Any other ideas?

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.6
Created-By: 1.7.0_80-b15 (Oracle Corporation)
X-Compile-Source-JDK: 1.7
X-Compile-Target-JDK: 1.7

Name: javax/servlet/
Specification-Title: Java API for Servlets
Specification-Version: 3.1
Specification-Vendor: Sun Microsystems, Inc.
Implementation-Title: javax.servlet
Implementation-Version: 3.1.FR
Implementation-Vendor: Apache Software Foundation

Comment: I was facing issues with activiti latest version so i am using activiti 5.14 it's working fine without any issues

Answer (score 0):

Exception in thread "Thread-7" org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Unknown property used in expression: ${notEnoughInformation == 'true'} at org.activiti.engine.impl.el.JuelExpression.getValue(JuelExpression.java:53)

From what I read here, it doesn't understand the property used in Thread-7. Make sure you are using the correct property. It doesn't have enough information and doesn't know what to do without that needed information.

Comment: I´m downloading the file (activiti zip) from the Github activiti page. Not sure what to change as i haven’t changed any files after downloading. Is there any dependency like it works only with Sun JDK? What need to be done here? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Kranis Are you using Maven? If so here is some information on it. http://activiti.org/community.html I'm not very familiar with activiti since I have never really used it. I just read the log and gave you what I found.